# How programatically authorize user into phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

To authorize users in phpMyAdmin (when specific condition meets in our application), we create a hidden form (with pre-filled username and password) and automatically (using JavaScript) submit that form so, we are doing this "trick":

```
if($condition)

   <form> <input user ....><input pass....> <auto-submit>

}
```

However, I was unable to find a way, to programmatically authorize users (without submitting form etc..)?

I tried:

```
$_POST['pma_username']=DB_USER;
$_POST['pma_password']=DB_PASSWORD;
$_POST['server']    =1;
$_POST['target']    ="index.php";
$_POST['token']        ="sample";

include (.........index.php);
```

But it doesn't authorize correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ["signon" authentication method](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#signon-authentication-mode), which is designed to allow authentication through a secondary login portal or to allow an SSO application to hand off credentials to phpMyAdmin.

Also, it's not [directly documented](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-access-directly-to-database-or-table-pages) in the URL query string section, but using a URL like http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master/index.php?pma_username=foo&pma_password=bar currently works, so that's a second option for you.

Comment: This `php_username=foo` trick no longer works :-(

Comment: Sadly that's true, phpMyAdmin changed that some time ago. Currently the signon method is the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need just two little steps to activate sso for your phpmyadmin installation:

**Inside the config.inc.php:**

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'signon';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'SingleSignOn';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'SignonSession';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL'] = 'index.php';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LogoutURL'] = 'sso-login.php?logout';
```

**And a script called sso-login.php in the root of phpmyadmin:**

```
<?php
define("PMA_SIGNON_INDEX", 2);
define('PMA_SIGNON_SESSIONNAME', 'SignonSession');
define('PMA_DISABLE_SSL_PEER_VALIDATION', TRUE);

session_name(PMA_SIGNON_SESSIONNAME);
@session_start();

/* logout request */
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 86400, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"] );
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

/* create phpMyAdmin session from response data */
$_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_user'] = "username";
$_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_password'] = "password";
$_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_host'] = defined("PMA_SIGNON_HOST") ? PMA_SIGNON_HOST : "hostname";
@session_write_close();
header('Location: index.php?server=' . PMA_SIGNON_INDEX);
```

That's all you need.

Comment: When you say `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL'] = 'index.php';` don't you mean sso-login.php rather than index.php?